# Model for localizable attribute values in Core Data Entity?

Tags: cocoa, database-design, core-data, localization, internationalization

If I want to create a entity in Core Data that has attributes with values that should be localizable I'm wondering how the most efficient way would look like?

As a example let's assume the following structure:

```
Book
    name (localizable)
    description (localizable)
    author
```

An localized book entry would look like this:

```
name:   "A great novel" (en/international),
        "Ein großartiger Roman" (de), 
        "Un grand roman" (fr)

description:
        "Great!" (en/international),
        "Großartig!" (de), 
        "Grand!" (fr)

author: "John Smith"
```

In a SQL/SQLite implementation I would use two tables. A *books* table containing the book information (author, the english/international name and description) and the *localizationBooks* table that is related using the primary key of the corresponding book. This second table contains the localized name and description values as well as the languageCode. This would allow to have a scalable number of localizations.

For fetching the data I would use a

```
SELECT COALESCE(localizationBooks.name, books.name)
```

to get the actual values for the given language code. This allows to use the international english value as fallback for unsupported languages.

Would this require a separate entity in Core Data (e.g. BookLocalization) that has a relation to the Book or is there another recommended way of doing this?

Answer (score 2):

The strategy you mention is usually the best. As you suggest, this requires an extra entity for the localized properties.

You can then write a helper method on your `Books` entity to get the appropriate localization object for a given language and use it like this:

```
[book bookLocalizationForLanguage:@"de"].name
```

You could even take it a step further and just add properties like `localizedName`, `localizedDescription` on the `Books` entity which will fetch the appropriate localized value.

Answer (score 0):

Well, despite that this topic is 3 years old... I just stumbled upon it, asking my self the very same as the original poster. I found another thread with an answer.

I'll just repeat it in here in case somebody else hits this thread (Answer from Gordon Hughes):

[Good practices for multiple language data in Core Data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2689570/good-practices-for-multiple-language-data-in-core-data)

**To summarize:**
Let's say you have Entity Books. Then you will have to make an additional one, called Localizedbook for example. In Books you have the attribute "title" and in LocalizedBook you have "localizedTitle" and "locale" for international strings like "en_US".

You now have to set the relationship between title -> localizedTitle (one to many, as one original title can have multiple translations).

So, every time you fetch "title" you will get the "localizedTitle" given to a specific locale, if the relations are set correctly.

Comment: Answers which just contain links are [considered bad practice](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers). Please summarize the content here (don't copy/paste) so the answer can stand on its own. If you don't you run the risk of your answer being removed, especially if the link ever dies.