# Good practices for multiple language data in Core Data

Tags: iphone, database, core-data

i need a multilingual coredata db in my iphone app. I could create different database for each language but i hope that in iphone sdk exist an automatically way to manage data in different language core data like for resources and string.

Someone have some hints?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I've done something similar to Shortseller, but without the use of categories.

[image]

`InternationalBook` and `LocalizedBook` are both custom managed objects with a one-to-many relationship (one international book to many localised books).

In the implementation of `InternationalBook`, I've added a custom accessor for `title`:

```
- (NSString *)title {
    [self willAccessValueForKey:@"title"];
    NSString *locTitle = nil;
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"locale==%@", [DataManager localeString]];
    NSSet *localizedSet = [self.localizedBook filteredSetUsingPredicate:predicate];
    if ([localizedSet count] > 0) {
        locTitle = [[localizedSet valueForKey:@"localizedTitle"] anyObject];
    }
    [self didAccessValueForKey:@"title"];
    return locTitle;
}
```

`[DataManager localeString]` is a class method which returns the user's language and country code: `en_US`, `fr_FR`, etc. See documentation on `NSLocale` for details.

See the "Custom Attribute and To-One Relationship Accessor Methods" section of the Core Data Programming Guide for an explanation of `willAccessValueForKey:` and `didAccessValueForKey:`.

When populating the data, I grab a string representing the user's current locale (`[DataManager localeString]`), and store that along the with localised book title in a new `LocalizedBook` object.  Each `LocalizedBook` instance is added to an `NSMutableSet`, which represents the one-to-many relationship.

```
NSMutableSet *bookLocalizations = [internationalBook mutableSetValueForKey:@"localizedBook"]; // internationalBook is an instance of InternationalBook
// set the values for locale and localizedTitle
LocalizedBook *localizedBook = (LocalizedBook *)[NSEntityDescription insertnNewObjectEntityForName:@"LocalizedBook" inManagedObjectContext:self.bookMOC];
localizedBook.locale = [DataManager localeString];
localizedBook.localizedTitle = theLocalizedTitle; // assume theLocalizedTitle has been defined.
[bookLocalizations addObject:localizedBook];
[bookLocalizations setValue:localizedBook forKey:@"localizedBook"];
```

Since the localised titles are being stored in the `LocalizedBook` managed object, you can make the `title` attribute a transient, but if you do that you can't use `title` in a predicate.

The nice thing about this approach is that the implementation of the to-many relationship is transparent to any consumers. You simply request `internationalBook.title` and the custom accessor returns the appropriate value based on the user's locale behind the scenes.

Comment: Excellent, but how do you manage the situation when a user changes locale? IMHO asking a user to restart the app is rude, but otherwise a lot of work must be done in order to update all fetched and shown text in all view controllers.

Answer (score 0):

I have generated model classes for the core data entities. 
Then I defined category helper classes with functions to set and get the multilanguage properties (e.g. name). 
So I have a Product (with e.g. code and price) and a ProductLanguage (with language and name properties) Entity. 
I never directly access ProductLanguage, but always use the name function defined on the the Product model (via category). This has worked well for me sofar.

Answer (score 0):

Like Gordon, I use quite similar code, but not written files generated by model. I use this code in my .m file where I want to show the data.
As I start from Apple template, I put this code exactly in 
 - (void)configureCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
of my TableViewController.m

P.S: Just to understand, I use these prefixes: tbl_ for tables (entities), rel_ for relationships, fld_ for fields (attributes).

Hope this helps.

```
NSSet *sourceSet = [NSSet setWithArray:[[tbl_MainTable rel_Localization]allObjects]];
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"fld_Locale == %@", [[NSLocale preferredLanguages] objectAtIndex:0]];
NSSet *filteredSet = [sourceSet filteredSetUsingPredicate:predicate];
//NSLog(@"%@", filteredSet); NSLog(@"%@", [[filteredSet valueForKey:@"fld_Name"] anyObject]);
if ([filteredSet count] > 0)
{
    [cell.detailTextLabel setText:[[filteredSet valueForKey:@"fld_Name"] anyObject]];
}
```