# CoreData overwriting Getter and Predicates

Tags: ios, macos, core-data

I'm trying to localize my Core Data app. I found different approaches and the one I'm interested most in, is described in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2689570/good-practices-for-multiple-language-data-in-core-data/2694059#2694059). Basically it creates a new table and overwrites the getter, to return the correct localization.

```
entity(Book, title, localizedTitle)

entity(LocalizedString, localization, string)
```

What I don't get right now, is, if it influences the predicate, too. Usually I would write a predicate like this:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"title = %@", someString];
```

In case the property title is in my CoreData Class via a category overwritten to be localized and `someString` is a user selection I search for. Does this compare the localized title with `someString`, or title?

So will the predicate use the overwritten property of `title` and return `localizedTitle` to compare it with `someString`, or will it use the empty `title` field to compare it to `someString`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to revoke the answer, since I found out, that when you override a getter, the NSPredicate will use the overridden getter. Some weird behavior, but seems like codeData does this.

Comment: For the NSPredicate it will **not** use the getter from the subclass of NSManagedObject for me. I tried it.

Comment: I wrote it yesterday and when using the overridden getter the NSPredicate resulted in some weird behavior. Had to create a new getter with localized title. I've used the same code of the question I mentioned above. Only difference, the getter is in a category. I am able to access the 'category-getter' though in NSPredicate and NSFetchedResultsController as sectionNameKeyPath. So the behavior might change with the versions? I'm using XCode 5.1.1 and iOS 7.

Answer (score 0):

The `NSPredicate` itself is not using any of your code if not inserted by you with the `%@`. It is a SQLite request inside a wrapper object `NSPredicate`. With title you are not using your title property (so the getter) in one of your wrapper CoraData Objects for a row in the database. `title` is only an access to a column in your database, nothing transient.

The customized getter you created is for receiving the data from the database through CoreData, packed each row into a wrapper object subclassed from `NSManagedObject`. If you access a property of this wrapper object it reads the data and localizes it lazily. So nothing from the data has changed.

---

I tested this with a little app to make sure!

Maybe we mean different things. I have a subclass of NSManaged Object. This subclass uses a custom getter to change the value of the NSManagedObject from @"butter" to @"milch".

The real value in the SQLite database (and only to make sure with @dynamic), the output is 'butter', but with the custom getter every other class I tried will get 'milch' as the attribute from CoreData except NSPredicate. The attribute is called 'name'. Now I use a NSPredicate

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: @"name = %@", @"milch"];
```

It is **not** using the getter. Since all objects would fulfill that predicate with the custom getter:

```
- (NSString *)name {
    return @"milch";
}
```

---

Maybe another stackoverflow answer is more precise:

[NSPredicate in NSFetchedResultsController doesn't use Category's getter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18558421/nspredicate-in-nsfetchedresultscontroller-doesnt-use-categorys-getter)

Comment: I'm not so sure I understand your answer. If I write a category this will not be used by the predicate, since CoreData calculates it's own properties? How would I need to rewrite my predicate then?

Comment: @Dimitri Updated the answer if you meant title

Comment: thanks so I have to write my predicate using the localized title.